# How is the right way to show each board level alternately on level up?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have create a game with unity c#. The player have "exp" which gain from something in the game. When the "exp" is enough the player will gain a level or usually we call it level up.

In my game player can gain 5 level at once if the "exp" reach 5 level experience.
So then the board will show 5 times with text inside from level 1 to 5.
Each board will alternately show when the player click OK and then the level board will show again with text another level.

**I have use a GUIANIMFREE system from assetstore which this is use for animated the UI move in or move out effect.**
So far i have done when level up show the board, but there is a mistake from my code. **The code is at below :**

```
void Start () {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("player").GetComponent<player> ();
        leveldb = GameObject.Find ("levelDatabase").GetComponent<levelDatabase> ();

        if (Player.level < 50) {
            nextLevel = Player.level + 1;
        }

        run = 1;
    }

void Awake() {
        if(enabled)
        {
            // Set GUIAnimSystemFREE.Instance.m_AutoAnimation to false in Awake() will let you control all GUI Animator elements in the scene via scripts.
            GUIAnimSystemFREE.Instance.m_AutoAnimation = false;
        }

        levelBoard.MoveOut (GUIAnimSystemFREE.eGUIMove.Self); **// This will Hide The Board Level First**
    }

void FixedUpdate () {
        if (run == 1) {
            ex = leveldb.levels.FindIndex (j => j.levelx == nextLevel); // **This is use to check nextLevel in LevelDatabase if there is a number level inside the db**
            if (ex >= 0) {
                if (Player.exp >= leveldb.levels [ex].exp1) { // **If Player Exp if Equal Larger then nextLevel Exp in database**
                    run = 0;
                    LevelUp (); // **Leveling Up**
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void LevelUp() {
        levelBoard.MoveIn (GUIAnimSystemFREE.eGUIMove.SelfAndChildren); // **Show The Board Level**
        Player.level = Player.level + 1;
        this.gameObject.transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI> ().text = Player.level.ToString (); // **Add the text number Level to board Child**
        Player.coin = Player.coin + leveldb.levels [ex].coin;
        Player.gem = Player.gem + leveldb.levels [ex].gem;
        this.gameObject.transform.GetChild (5).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI> ().text = "+" + leveldb.levels [ex].coin.ToString();
        this.gameObject.transform.GetChild (6).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI> ().text = "+" + leveldb.levels [ex].gem.ToString();

    }

    public void OnClickOKLevelBoard() {
        levelBoard.MoveOut (GUIAnimSystemFREE.eGUIMove.SelfAndChildren); //**Close the Board Level When OK is clicked**
        if (Player.level < 50) {
            nextLevel = Player.level + 1;
        }
        run = 1;
    }
```

**The Database Level is Like this :**
*With Paramater : Level, Exp Start From, Exp End From, Coin, Gem, prize1, prize2, prize3)*

```
levels.Add (new level (1, 5, 29, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0));
        levels.Add (new level (2, 30, 179, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0)); 
        levels.Add (new level (3, 180, 209, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0));
        levels.Add (new level (4, 210, 349, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0));
        levels.Add (new level (5, 350, 499, 0, 130, 0, 0, 0));
        levels.Add (new level (6, 500, 639, 1, 150, 0, 0, 0));
        levels.Add (new level (7, 640, 759, 1, 200, 0, 0, 0));
        levels.Add (new level (8, 760, 879, 2, 240, 0, 0, 0));
        levels.Add (new level (9, 880, 969, 2, 260, 0, 0, 0));
        levels.Add (new level (10, 970, 1119, 2, 300, 0, 0, 0));
```

When I Add 500 Exp to Player, from the levels Database if Player Level start from 0 then this will reach until level 6 as we can see at the database level 6 Exp start from 500.

**Let's we say we add 500 Exp to player. What happen in the code is :**

1. Level Board show up. Show Reach Level : 1    In here when i click
   OK.
2. Level Board is hide. And Then Show up again. Show Reach Level : 2.
   In here without i click OK the Level Board is hide and then never
   show up again.

**This is a mistake because it should show 6 time until level 6.**

What i want when add 500 Exp to Player is :

1. Level Board show up. Show Reach level : 1   in here when i click OK.
2. Level Board is hide. And Then Show up again. Show Reach Level : 2.
   in here when i click OK.
3. Level Board is hide. And Then Show up again. Show Reach Level : 3.
   in here when i click OK.
4. Level Board is hide. And Then Show up again. Show Reach Level : 4.
   in here when i click OK.
5. Level Board is hide. And Then Show up again. Show Reach Level : 5.
   in here when i click OK.
6. Level Board is hide. And Then Show up again. Show Reach Level : 6.
   in here when i click OK.
7. Level Board end show. And never show again until player Exp Reach
   Next Level Exp.

***Note : I am using fixedupdate() to check looping if the exp is reach the level exp.***

How to do it ? I think my logic is right. But when run in editor it is not going like it must.

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: can you use a breakpoint to test how many times LevelUp() is hit? my gut says it may be a threading issue related to the run variable.

Comment: hi @prof1990 I have test debug how many times LevelUp() is calling. It is only twice (2). When i click OK it must call again the Level Board (LevelUp()) But without click OK in second times the Level Board is disappear..

Comment: I suggest inspecting the if(ex >= 0) if that one fails nothing happens any more, maybe you should make  it throw an exception if( ex < 0 && player.lvl != maxLevel ) since it would completely break the game and possibly provide exploits and unnoticed bugs later on in development.

Comment: I have solve it. I do not sure too what is the problem. But it's seem it is a about timing the code run. How fast the code is running. Please see my posting answer. If you could figure it the real problem. But the code is running well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changing how the way to put the code.

```
void Start () {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("player").GetComponent<player> ();
        leveldb = GameObject.Find ("levelDatabase").GetComponent<levelDatabase> ();

        if (Player.level < 50) {
            nextLevel = Player.level + 1;
        }

        StartCoroutine (startcheck ());

    }

IEnumerator startcheck() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
        if (go == true) {
            Debug.Log ("DOING SOMETHING : " + i);
            i++;
            ex = leveldb.levels.FindIndex (j => j.levelx == nextLevel);
            if (ex >= 0) {
                if (Player.exp >= leveldb.levels [ex].exp1) {
                    go = false;
                    LevelUp ();
                    Debug.Log ("MASUK : " + Player.exp + " : " + leveldb.levels [ex].exp1);
                } else {
                    Start ();
                }
            } else {
                Start ();
            }
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("NOT DOING ANTYHTING");
        }

    }

public void LevelUp() {
        levelBoard.ResetAllChildren ();
        levelBoard.MoveIn (GUIAnimSystemFREE.eGUIMove.SelfAndChildren);
        Player.level = Player.level + 1;
        this.gameObject.transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI> ().text = Player.level.ToString ();
        Player.coin = Player.coin + leveldb.levels [ex].coin;
        Player.gem = Player.gem + leveldb.levels [ex].gem;
        this.gameObject.transform.GetChild (5).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI> ().text = "+" + leveldb.levels [ex].coin.ToString();
        this.gameObject.transform.GetChild (6).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI> ().text = "+" + leveldb.levels [ex].gem.ToString();

    }

public void OnClickOKLevelBoard() {
        levelBoard.MoveOut (GUIAnimSystemFREE.eGUIMove.Self);
        go = true;
        if (Player.level < 50) {
            nextLevel = Player.level + 1;
        } else {
            go = false;
        }

        Start ();
    }
```

Like This the Level Board is showup as many as exp reach the level.

Comment: Could be that move-in and move-out conflict, if still moving in one direction the other is ignored. I have no way of testing this, but if you want to know you can test it for yourself. Glad to see you fixed it anyway.

Comment: Yes i think the problem is from the GUIANIMFREE the move-in and move-out take a time to run. Thanks